# tweetinvi - No error, no tweet

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I am trying to send a tweet with an image from disk. My current code is below:

```
try
        {
            Auth.SetUserCredentials(consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken, accesstokenSecret);
            Tweet.PublishTweetWithImage(message, File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
        }
        catch (Tweetinvi.Exceptions.TwitterException x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
        }
```

The code appears to run, no exception is returned, but yet the tweet is not posted. Appreciate any help or insight.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation for ExceptionHandler : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Exception-Handling.

`ExceptionHandler.SwallowWebExceptions = false;`

The exception will then be raised.